# How to lerp colors that are in separate meshes

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

I have 2 separate meshes, one with shallow, and one with deep water. I need to lerp the colors to make the transition nicer. I can't merge the meshes together or else I will get the mesh has too many vertices error. Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: If the main issue is actually the amount of vertices have you considered setting the [`Mesh.indexFormat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html) to `32 bit (supports up to 4 billion vertices)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap to colours here's a basic script to fade one object's color to anothers over 5 seconds.

```
[SerializeField]
Renderer object1 = null;
[SerializeField]
Renderer object2 = null;

Color Color1;
Color Color2;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Color1 = object1.material.color;
    Color2 = object2.material.color;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float lerp = Time.time / 5 * Time.deltaTime;
    object1.material.color = Color.Lerp(object1.material.color, Color2, lerp);
    object2.material.color = Color.Lerp(object2.material.color, Color1, lerp);
}
```

}